# Is it possible to wake a machine from ARD?

Tags: apple-remote-desktop

Is it possible to wake a machine from ARD ? I have issues sometimes connecting to machines if they are in sleepmode and sometimes have to walk over to the machines and manually take them out of sleep mode before i can connect with ARD ?

Comment: I had read somewhere and now can't find the citation that WOL requires a wired (EG not WiFi) network connection. But yes ARD does that. Make sure all systems are up to date with the latest ARD client.

Answer (score 1):

Your network needs to be able to send WOL (wake-on-LAN) packets to the machines affected. If your network is subnetted, the problem becomes more difficult, if not impossible, without router config magic. This [thread at Apple Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4765550) explains the details more succinctly, and offers some solutions.

When I was managing 300+ Macs on two campuses **more than a decade ago**, it was impossible to wake any Macs from sleep reliably with ARD, so I set the Macs to spin down the hard drives when not in use and set the monitor sleep to a relatively short duration. The Macs never slept during the school day, and to save power, I used `pmset` commands to turn the Macs off after the close of the school day, and start up before school started on the morning. Naturally, people being who they are, some folks would power-down manually when they were done, but there was nothing I could do about it.

We now use JAMF JSS to manage our Mac fleet, which is thin on desktops -- laptops are the machine of choice. ARD has fallen by the wayside. I loved using it, but I'm no longer doing any serious Mac administration.

Comment: Thanks @iconDaemon, fortunately i dont have the computers on separate subnets but i do sometimes access the LAN remotely over a VPN. In that instance is it possible to send a WOL packet over a VPN without router config ?

Comment: This [dense Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/285359/can-wake-on-lan-work-on-vpn-connection) at ServerFault may give you some insight. I have not done deep networking configuration for quite some time -- I leave that to somebody with many years of experience at my school. I, unfortunately, have no more information to impart to you. Please see the edit to my answer for further elucidation.